# Attachments and Cc details sent to "reply to" email id not showing up

Tags: marketing-cloud, emailfileattachment, reply-mail-management

When the email recipient replies to the "reply-to" email address (configured in RMM) by adding an attachment and also adds Cc email id while replying, the attachments and Cc details are not showing up in reply-to email Inbox.

The person who is in Cc is able to see the attachments and Cc details correctly.

I tried to search SFMC RMM documentation around this but there nothing much that I could find.

Can anyone guide?

Answer (score 1):

Including attachments in the forwarded message is possible by requesting the "Preserve Reply Attachments" feature at the SFMC account executive explaining the use case for that.

This is what the documentation says about the "Preserve Reply Attachments" feature:

> RMM can support the forwarding of attachments in certain instances.
> Contact your Marketing Cloud account representative for more
> information on enabling the use of attachments with RMM.
> (Source: [Marketing Cloud Documentation - Reply Mail Management for Marketing Cloud Email](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_reply_mail_management.htm&type=5))

Preserving the CC isn't possible as this would mean that the copy is sent twice due to how RMM works (email is sent to SFMC RMM and then forwarded - so if the initial email to SFMC RMM already sent the copy the forward cannot include it again to not send it twice).

However, it should be possible to parse the CC header from the personalization String "_RMM_Headers" that is available if you use the "forward using triggered send" feature. You then also have to use a personalization string to add the body of the reply. Here's the list of RMM specific personalization strings:

- _RMM_Headers
- _RMM_ReplyBodyText
- _RMM_ReplyBodyHTML
- _RMM_ReplySubject
- _RMM_JobID
- _RMM_ListID
- _RMM_BatchID
- _RMM_SubscriberID
- _RMM_RecipientEmailAddress
- _RMM_RecipientSubscriberKey